# Ugly Arial font rendering with wkhtmltopdf.exe

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

Looking af https://wkhtmltopdf.org to render HTML to PDF

What can be done to improve the horrific rendering of a standard font link Arial?

**HTML**

```html
<div style="font-family:'Arial'; font-size:11px; font-weight:100;">THIS is my test size:11 weight:100</div>
```

**Command line**

```
PS C:\Users\me\test> echo "<div style=""font-family:'Arial'; font-size:11px; font-weight:100; "">THIS is my test size:11 weight:100</div>" | .\wkhtmltopdf.exe - test.pdf
```

**Rendered result**
[image]

**Expected result**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with a webfont (which was not installed by default in the system). I could only solve it including the `base64` font in the style.css passed to `user-style-sheet`. [Reference here](https://blog.shaharia.com/use-google-web-fonts-for-wkhtmltopdf-tools-to-convert-html-to-pdf)

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Arial';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url(data:font/opentype;charset=utf-8;base64,d09GRgABAAAAAD00AA4A---[large string ommited]----3MAuAH/hbAEjQA=) format("woff"),
    url(data:font/truetype;charset=utf-8;base64,AAEAAAARAQAABAAQRFNJRwAAAAEAAJUIAAA---[large string ommited]-----wAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAA) format("truetype");
}
```

You can use a tool like [this](https://transfonter.org/) to transform your font to `base64`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks that helped. I have used https://transfonter.org/ to convert my font and I had to use the autohint option for it to work perfectly.